# Redirection - Different Website from Different Computer

Tags: network, phishing, spoofing, url-redirection, web

There are URLs which its only purpose is to redirect the HTTP requestor to a correct website. Say, if I tried to access example.com/0wa/RaNd0m from my computer, it would redirect me to wikipedia.com. But if I tried it from my Virtual Machine in AWS, it would redirect me to a malicious site. Why is the final web page different for every different computer? Can you explain the step-by-step (technical) process of how this works? I believe this happens because the redirection proxy is checking the IP address and then sends the requestor accordingly. Please correct me if I am wrong.

If I wanted to analyze the malicious website, I would frequently have to log in to one of my AWS virtual machines (each having different Public IP) and then visit the URL. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of redirecting the requestor to the site you want. Your idea is a good option because you are able to focus people from different countries depending on the focus of an attack. If it needs to be a bit easier you can check the User Agent, OS, Language and other variables that will be sent by a browser. If you want to focus a Windows PC you check the agent and redirect to the malicious site. If an iPhone is surfing to the same site there could be another reaction depending on the attackers needs. This method generates not that much overhead as it doesn’t need to involve other servers to check the origin of the IP address.

> If I wanted to analyze the malicious website, I would frequently have to log in to one of my AWS virtual machines (each having different Public IP) and then visit the URL. Is there a better way of doing this?

If you want to analyze a Webpage on their behavior it depends on the language of the Page (PHP,JS,…) If it is written in JS it’s easy because you can request the page and look into the source code. If the redirecting function is server side implemented you have to try all User Agents, different IPs and mixtures to get the full information what combination redirects you to which page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you think Burpsuit would help me by changing the headers of the request?

Comment: Yes I would give it a try. If not, then it´s maybe your idea with the ip origin.